# Absorption line of nitrogen at 337 nm

Tags: laser, absorption

Nitrogen laser emits a laser at 337 nm. So, I think nitrogen has a laser absorption spectrum at 337 nm, but I have not found any information such as absorption coefficients around this wavelength from the Hitran database. Where should I get its absorption spectrum at 337nm?

Comment: The $337$ nm transition is $C^3\pi u \to B^3\pi g$